# Convert from void * to int

Tags: c

I'm working on a school project and I'm having trouble converting from 'void *' to 'int'. How can I do that?

example:

```
void *search(void *id) {
   int i;
}
```

How do I store the integer in id in i?

Comment: You might not be able to .... Consider using [`intptr_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer) from `<stdint.h>`

Comment: In general, you cannot, since they may be different sizes.

Comment: You sure that the void* is the int, and not pointing to it?

Comment: For what purpose are you casting the void pointer?

Comment: You have to give us some context. What is `search`? How is it called? With what arguments? What is the function supposed to do? Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us. And [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: search is a function that I'm using to locate a certain string in a file using threads. I call search on using a for to create threads: pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, search, &i); @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: @DiogoSilva If the true goal is to "locate a certain string", what does finding an `int` have to do with that?  Sounds like the goal is to find the _address of a string_ and not find an `int`.

Comment: And what is `i`? Is it a loop variable? You ***really*** need to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) show us. Because what you are doing might lead to some obscure bugs.

Comment: Yes, more code, because 'pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, search, &i);' is not filling me with happy thoughts, notably that last argument:(   @Someprogrammerdude is worried too, and with good reason..

Answer (score 3):

You need to cast the pointer to an `int *`, then dereference the pointer.

```
int i = *(int *)id;
```

Answer (score 3):

> Convert from void * to int

Easy, cast with `(int)`.  A `void*` can always be converted to an `int`.  Yet this may lose information and might not be OP's true goal.  If the goal it to truly convert a `void*` pointer to some integer and not lose information, consider the optional integer types `(u)intptr_t`

```
void *search1(void *id) {
  int i = (int) id;
  ...
}
```

---

> How do I store the integer in id in i?

If an `int` is located at the memory pointed to by `id`, then cast to an `int*` and de-reference.

```
void *search2(void *id) {
  int *ip = (int *) id;
  int i = *ip;   // or in one step *((int *) id)
  ...
}
```

If the pointer `id` did not originate from a valid `int*`, then the result is *undefined behavior* (UB).